# AppleKeyboards in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I used AppleKeyboards to get users' keyboard setting before iOS6:

```
NSArray * keyboards = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleKeyboards"];
for (int i = 0; i < [keyboards count]; i++)
{
  NSLog(@"%@", [keyboards objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

But after iOS6, I can't use AppleKeyboards as key for the user setting.
Is there any solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use UITextInputMode Class to get current text input mode by "+ (UITextInputMode *)currentInputMode".

see also: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html