# Get keyboards currently enabled in Settings?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, social-networking, weibo, sinaweibo

Is there any way to identify which keyboards are enabled in Settings?

Sharing to Sina Weibo is only possible if a Chinese keyboard is enabled, so I'd like to only show the "Sina Weibo" action sheet button if a Chinese keyboard is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by Guy, there is a better way to do this. I've updated my own code to use the following:

```
NSArray *keyboards = [UITextInputMode activeInputModes];
for (UITextInputMode *mode in keyboards) {
    NSString *name = mode.primaryLanguage;
    if ([name hasPrefix:@"zh-Han"]) {
        // One of the Chinese keyboards is installed
        break;
    }
}
```

Swift: (**Note**: Broken under iOS 9.x due to a bad declaration for `UITextInputMode activeInputModes`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32708052/1226963) for a workaround.)

```
let keyboards = UITextInputMode.activeInputModes()
for var mode in keyboards  {
    var primary = mode.primaryLanguage
    if let lang = primary {
        if lang.hasPrefix("zh") {
            // One of the Chinese keyboards is installed
            break
        }
    }
}
```

---

Old approach:

I don't know if this is allowed or not in an App Store app, but you could do:

```
NSArray *keyboards = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleKeyboards"];
for (NSString *keyboard in keyboards) {
    if ([keyboard hasPrefix:@"zh_Han"]) {
        // One of the Chinese keyboards is installed
    }
}
```

It's possible that if the user only has a default keyboard for their locale, there won't be an entry for the `AppleKeyboards` key. In this case, you may want to check the user's locale. If the locale is for China, then you chould assume they have a Chinese keyboard.

Comment: Works great, thanks.

The code for checking current language is

`if ([[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] hasPrefix:@"zh"]) {
                    // current language is Chinese
            }`

Comment: This solution is hacky. You guys should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816325/applekeyboards-in-ios6

Comment: @GuyKogus Yes, this may be a little "hacky" but it works. The question you link to does not answer this question. Your link is for determining the current keyboard, not for seeing if a given keyboard is available.

Comment: It works for getting the available keyboards. I've tried this on both iOS 6 & 7.

Comment: @GuyKogus It seems I misread what that class does. I just tried it out and sure enough using `UITextInputMode activeInputModes` does reflect the selected keyboards. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**This code is really helpful for me to identify keyboard extension is activated or not in device settings from parent app itself:**

```
    //Put below function in app delegate...

    public func isKeyboardExtensionEnabled() -> Bool {
        guard let appBundleIdentifier = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier else {
            fatalError("isKeyboardExtensionEnabled(): Cannot retrieve bundle identifier.")
        }

        guard let keyboards = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation()["AppleKeyboards"] as? [String] else {
            // There is no key `AppleKeyboards` in NSUserDefaults. That happens sometimes.
            return false
        }

        let keyboardExtensionBundleIdentifierPrefix = appBundleIdentifier + "."
        for keyboard in keyboards {
            if keyboard.hasPrefix(keyboardExtensionBundleIdentifierPrefix) {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }


    // Call it from below delegate method to identify...

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

            if(isKeyboardExtensionEnabled()){            
                showAlert(message: "Hurrey! My-Keyboard is activated");
            }
            else{
                showAlert(message: "Please activate My-Keyboard!");
            }

        }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

            if(isKeyboardExtensionEnabled()){            
                showAlert(message: "Hurrey! My-Keyboard is activated");
            }
            else{
                showAlert(message: "Please activate My-Keyboard!");
            }
        }
```