# UITextInputMode.activeInputModes() crashes in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextinput

I want to get UITextInputMode in Swift 2 but `UITextInputMode.activeInputModes()` crashes.

```
    let x = UITextInputMode.activeInputModes() // crash here

    for t in x {
        print(t)
    }
```

Comment: Crash log would be  useful here

Comment: @ glyuck yes, but there is no log output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in Xcode 7 as mentioned [HERE](http://www.openradar.me/22643142). Which says:

> Summary:
>
> Prior to the Xcode 7 GM, `UITextInputMode.activeInputModes()` returned
>   an array of `UITextInputMode` instances. However, in the Xcode 7 GM, the
>   method signature in the header file and documentation states that it
>   returns an array of Strings, which is incorrect. As a result, code
>   that uses `activeInputModes` correctly no longer compiles, and
>   attempting to use `activeInputModes` in a Playground throws an
>   exception.

Comment: Hey here I am almost a year after this question was first asked and I just encountered this bug again. Any work around not envloving a Bridge-header for this issue? Or we need to wait one more year? thanks

Answer (score 10):

I was able to work around this bug by using an Objective-C bridge.

Bridge.h

```
#ifndef Bridge_h
#define Bridge_h

#import "Kludge.h"

#endif
```

Kludge.h

```
#ifndef Kludge_h
#define Kludge_h

#import <UIKit/UITextInput.h>

@interface Kludge : NSObject

+ (NSArray<UITextInputMode *> *)activeInputModes;

@end

#endif
```

Kludge.m

```
#import "Kludge.h"

@implementation Kludge

+ (NSArray<UITextInputMode *> *)activeInputModes {
  return (NSArray<UITextInputMode *> *)[UITextInputMode activeInputModes];
}

@end
```

From Swift, you can now call Kludge.activeInputModes() and get the correct results.

Comment: This is really a good idea. I try this and work fine. Could you also see my another question [how to detect if app use not system IME keyboard in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706996/how-to-detect-if-app-use-not-system-ime-keyboard-in-swift)

Comment: Pretty smart. Hope apple will fix this ASAP.